# SQL code for Comparing date fields in different rows and combining the results

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I need help for proper Oracle SQL code to combine rows for a crystal reports command object. This is a part of the bigger query I'm working on and got stuck for the past couple of days.

for eg. if the columns are like below

```
PatId   In_time                     Out_time  
151     01/01/2012 07:00:00 am      01/01/2012 10:00:00 am
151     01/01/2012 11:00:00 am      01/02/2012 08:00:00 am 
151     01/02/2012 11:00:00 am      01/02/2012 01:00:00 pm
151     01/03/2012 08:00:00 am      01/03/2012 03:00:00 pm
151     01/06/2012 03:30:00 pm      01/09/2012 07:00:00 am
167     01/03/2012 01:30:00 pm      01/09/2012 07:00:00 am
167     01/13/2012 03:30:00 pm      01/14/2012 07:00:00 am
167     01/14/2012 11:30:00 am      01/15/2012 11:30:00 am
167     01/18/2012 12:00:00 pm      01/19/2012 03:00:00 am
```

Within a PatId, the code should compare the Out_time of one row to the In_time of the next row, and check whether the time gap is greater than 48 hours. If not, then it is considered part of the same visit.  I want one result row per PatID & visit, with min(In_time) and max(Out_time).  The time span of the visit (result row) itself may be greater than 48 hours.

For this example, for PatId 151 the time difference between the out_time of 1st row and In_time of 2nd row is less than 48 hours. The difference between Out_time of second row and In_time of 3rd row, as well as between the 3rd and 4th rows, is also less than 48 hours.  After this the gap between Out_time of the 4th row and In_time of 5th row is greater than 48 hours.  The result for PatId 151 should be as below and same for EmpId 167, the chaining should continue until a gap greater than 48 hours is found.

So the result for the above table should be displayed as,

```
PatId     In_time                          Out_time  
151     01/01/2012 07:00:00 am      01/03/2012 03:00:00 pm
151     01/06/2012 03:30:00 pm      01/09/2012 07:00:00 am
167     01/03/2012 01:30:00 pm      01/09/2012 07:00:00 am
167     01/13/2012 03:30:00 pm      01/15/2012 11:30:00 am
167     01/18/2012 12:00:00 pm      01/19/2012 03:00:00 am
```

I could not get the logic on how to compare and merge rows.

Thanks in Advance, Abhi

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean by "*merge*"?

Comment: What happens if the *third* row's date is also within 48 hours of the second's--should it continue chaining, or not? And what is the `c1` column? Also, what have you tried? Show some effort.

Comment: The example shows the first three rows being grouped or "merged" into one row in the sample result.  What is not discussed is what to do if there is never a significant break.  What happens if there is a row for every day in a month for example.  How do you decide where to stop?

Comment: @ErikE : It should continue chaining until it finds the 48 hours difference. I tried get the min(dt1) and group it by c1, but i dont know how to collapse result set as shown above. c1 is the employee and dt1 and dt2 are the in and out times. Unless datediff of dt2 of one column and dt1 of the next column should be less than 48hours and so on

Comment: @WarrenT: It stops at max(dt2). There will not be a case when there is never a break. This is the part of a monthly report i need to run ( crystal report command object)

Comment: @WarrenT but the example has the first two rows adjacent/touching so it was not clear if it applied to the general rule of "within 48 hours" or if it was a special case about contiguous ranges.

Comment: So you will never have records for 3 or 4 consecutive days?  Please consider redefining this question more precisely, as it seems unclear or imprecise to many who consider answering it.

Comment: It might help if you outline the real world scenario, so that the reporting logic you are attempting will become easier to understand precisely, and help avoid answers that miss the mark.

Comment: @WarrenT: I modified my question and tried to be more precise. Please check and see if makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Experiment here if you like:  [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da9a7](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da9a7)

Comment: @Abhi What if the 4th input row had an in_time of `1/03/2012 06:00:00 am` ?  Would that be grouped with the others?  What if it was `1/02/2012 08:00:00 pm`?  The definition of the 48 hour window is not clear to me.  Also suppose (even in error) that the records have overlapping times.  If you explain the reasoning behind the 48 hour window, and perhaps something of what this data is about, it may help make this clearer, and thus get you a better answer.

Comment: @WarrenT: The real world scenario is the EmpID is actually a sample Patient ID. The In_time and out_time refers to the time when they are moved to a bed and out. They will move from one bed to another, so NO OVERLAPPING. If the time difference between Out_time and In_time of two consecutive rows is greater than 48 hours we consider it another visit to the hospital, If not we consider it to be single visit and then combine them.

Comment: @Abhi Thank you, that clarifies the situation greatly, which in turn makes it easier to understand what the rules should be.  I edited your question based on your clarification.  Perhaps that will encourage people to see this as a more "worthy" question.  And one that may take a bit of thought to solve. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

General example of subtracting time - copy/paste to see the output. This example will give you differences in hours, minutes, seconds between two dates. The basic formula is (end_date - start_date) * 86400 (number of seconds in 24 hrs)...:

```
SELECT trunc(mydate / 3600) hr
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60) mnt
     , trunc(mod(mydate, 3600) / 60 /60) sec
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT (to_date('01/03/2012 10:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss') -
           to_date('01/01/2012 07:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss')) * 86400 mydate
     FROM dual
  )
 /

 HR | MNT | SEC
 ---------------
 51 |  0  |  0
```

You need to check your example and logic. I could not understand what needs to be comnpared with what...

Comment: Sorry, but this in not what I'm looking for. I modified my question and made it a little more precise. I'm actually looking to compare Out_time of 1st row to In_time 2nd column and check for time difference of 48 hours. I also posted the results set of what I need.